# Changing user password with passwd not possible. Error "passwd: sorry"

Tags: freebsd, password

I have a FreeBSD Server and a strange problem. Everytime some tries to change a password he gets this

```
~$ passwd
Changing local password for <USER>
Old Password:
passwd: sorry
```

The root account is unaffected.

I can't find any clues in the logs. I don't use LDAP for authentification and the server is running in a jail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code was so short and simple that it only took a moment to find the only place within FreeBSD's `passwd` utility where that particular message is printed.

Specifically, it occurs when PAM has failed to authenticate the user. In other words, one of these things:

1. You mistyped the old password.
2. `passwd` doesn't have the proper permissions; it must be setuid root.
3. Your local PAM setup is horribly broken; if this were the case, nobody would be able to log in.

My bets are on 2.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I can rule out 1. and 2., so it must be 3. but I can't remember changing PAM and I can log in via SSH.

Comment: SSH may not use PAM, depending on how it's set up.

Comment: It is PAM ... but I can't seem to find the error

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with NIS. Check nsswitch.conf and disable the use of NIS or YP (Yellow Pages). Then see whether the problem has gone away.